# Blip Scripts: JSON to JavaScript - Array is Undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a project to create a bot on Blip. And in some parts I need to make a request to an API and use a script (JavaScript) to get the elements of the JSON response.

I received that JSON from the API as `requestResponse` variable:

```
{
    "procedimentos": [
        {
            "pro_cod": "00003069",
            "pro_nome": "ACIDO FOLICO",
            "pro_tipo": "P",
            "subgrupo": {
                "sgr_codcomposto": "03001",
                "sgr_nome": "LAB1(0,5)"
            }
        },
        {
            "pro_cod": "00003077",
            "pro_nome": "ACIDO ÚRICO",
            "pro_tipo": "P",
            "subgrupo": {
                "sgr_codcomposto": "03001",
                "sgr_nome": "LAB1(0,5)"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The variable is a parameter of the following function:

```
function run(requestResponse) {
    let requestObject = JSON.parse(requestResponse);

    return requestObject.procedimentos[0].pro_nome;
};
```

The result I got is that `procedimentos` is undefined. Please, help!!!

Comment: Then `requestResponse` doesn't contain what you think it does. This could be because of hidden/non-printable characters, trying to access it before the request has actually completed, or it has a different shape than you expect. I'd sanity-check your expectations (#1 and #3) then verify the async code flow.

Comment: Your question does not have enough information to answer. We can only speculate. Perhaps the "requestResponse" is not text and is some sort of "Promise" object. You should inspect it by logging it to the console.
`console.log(requestResponse)` to see what it is.

Comment: I tried . and result ACIDO FOLICO

Comment: If `procedimentos` is `undefined` that means that the `requestObject` doesn't have it. Are you sure that the `requestObject` is not just a `Promise` that gets resolved later?

Answer (score 0):

The script was right! The problem is because when the JSON API response is too big, Blip doesn't accept it and put the string `{REDUCED:true}` as the response. So, `requestResponse` didn't have the array. Thank you all that helped me.